# Autoloading in Hack / HHVM

Tags: php, loader, autoload, hhvm, hacklang

I am having some trouble getting the autoloader to work in Hack / HHVM.

I am mainly a PHP developer, but decided to try Hack for this new project I am working on.

My project hierarchy looks like this:

- autoload.php
- Database/DatabaseConnection.php
- AppSupport/GetSomething.php

autoload.php looks like:

```
<?hh // strict

function setupAutoload(): void {
    $map = array(
        'class' => array('A' => 'Database/DatabaseConnection.php'),
        'failure' => function($kind, $name) { echo "Autoload fail: $kind, $name\n"; }
    );

    \HH\autoload_set_paths($map, '/var/www/html/');
}

setupAutoload();
```

Database/DatabaseConnection looks like:

```
<?hh // strict

class DatabaseConnection {
    // All my db connect code
}
```

and finally AppSupport/GetSomething.php looks like:

```
<?hh // strict

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/autoload.php';

$pdo = new DatabaseConnection('localhost', NULL, 'XXXX', 'YYYY', 'ZZZZ');
$stmt = $pdo->getLink()->prepare('SELECT * FROM test');
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($res);
```

When I run GetSomething.php I am getting `Class undefined: DatabaseConnection`

I am not getting any errors with the autoloader though... What is weird though is that if I replace

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/autoload.php';
```

with

```
require_once '/var/www/html/Database/DatabaseConnection.php';
```

directly it works fine.

I must be missing something silly... Thanks!

Comment: Is it a typo that, instead of 'Database', you're mapping 'A' to 'Database/DatabaseConnection.php'?